# Gap under Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I started with the HTML5 Boilerplate, then added a BootStrap Carousel. The idea is to have a standard template, so I can resize a few images from the customer and have a solid start on their customization for a responsive layout.
I'm trying to close the gap at the bottom of the carousel and still keep the jumbotron at a standard height. I'm pretty sure it's coming from the `.carousel-inner>.item {height: 20em;}` I've tried changing this to a percentage to no avail,   `.carousel-inner>.item {height: 20%;}`  what am I not understanding?

**Main.CSS**

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
    height: 20em;
}

.carousel-inner>.item img {
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    /*
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    */
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Index.HTML**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">

            <picture>
                <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="../img/Pressure_Wash_320.jpg">
                <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="../img/Pressure_Wash.jpg">
                <img src="../img/Pressure_Wash.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
            </picture>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="../img/Capture2.PNG" alt="Chicago">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="../img/Capture3.PNG" alt="New York">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>


<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: capture4]

[github/Carousel/issue 2](https://github.com/TurtleWolf/CarouselTemplate/issues/2)

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the markup that creates the problem here, not a third party site which can change or disappear tomorrow: [mcve] Do NOT post [images of code!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: something was sticking in the markdown editor.. I think I've got it fixed now, but I had to post it to keep from loosing the rest

Comment: I'm a little confused by the `position: absolute`... What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: That came from a previous question on the same project.. I'm willing to change it, if you think that's what's causing the issue I'll try deleting it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229692/let-carousel-images-cover-their-div

Comment: I think it was to keep the jumbotron steady.. I was trying to keep it at a standard horizontal position, instead of jumping up and down per each slide.

Comment: I've changed it to relative and deleted it completely.. neither seem to have any effect at all, I think it was connected to how he was suggesting i center the images from top to bottom with transform: -50%; but I took that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue on mobile you'll need to do the following (replacing your styles above):

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
  height: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-inner > .item {
    height: 20em;
  }

  .carousel-inner > .item img {
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

The reason for the gap is because the images in the carousel have `max-width: 100%` set but the carousel item itself has a fixed height. As you scale down the viewport, the image height gets smaller than the carousel `.item` and leaves a gap beneath it.

The workaround applies the `.item` height only to viewports greater than or equal to 768px leaving the smaller screens to natively scale based on the image height.

As with everything, there are caveats to this and it may need tweaking based on your final spec. For example, it would be beneficial to resize all images in the carousel to a uniform size so that you don't have weird jumping as it scrolls through them.

**Codepen example:** https://codepen.io/raptorkraine/pen/PJzeMp

**Additional**

You can add additional breakpoints and adjust the height of the `.item` class accordingly or substitute for a `vh` unit height if it works better for you.